# Returning position where a label wraps text (tkinter)

Tags: python, text, tkinter, label

I was wondering if it was possible to return the position or character where a label wraps text, as I would like to append a "\n" into the string being printed in the label after said character. Believe it or not, I do have a good reason for doing this, although it is somewhat complicated to explain.

Comment: Better do not use label but use the Text Widget. You can layout it so it looks like a Label. I did not hear it was possible with a Label.

Comment: of course it is possible with a label. using textvariable, you can always .get the value, edit and set it. this is far more complicated using text widgets. still, i am not sure what exactly OP tried to do though. an example would be nice.

Comment: @Jon I think you only want the **position** where the label wraps text because the same character can occur multiple times

Comment: i think he just want to have a new line when the text is wider than the label. for this purpose `wraplength` should do the trick. put `wraplength = 10` into your labeldeclaration to limit the number of characters per line to 10. "Detecting" if a Label ends to have a new line is what OP tries to do i guess.

Comment: @user1451340 I think what you originally said would have been better. Due to the way I handle the label (and it constantly has text going into it) simply wrapping the text pushes it out of sight at the bottom of the label instead. Currently, when there are too many lines (checked by the number of "\n"'s there are) it pops the first part off the string, thus allowing to have more at the bottom of the label. It's probably overly complicated, but this seemed to be the best way to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @Jon i am still note entirely sure what exactly you do, but if it works, fine :)